# PDO Delete Query in PHP does not take effect

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using the below code to delete all rows from the mysql table but it does not take any effect. I am also not getting any errors - it just says record Record deleted successfully. I don't know if there is any backend safe mode enabled or I need to do additional commits but all the data is still in the database.

```
<?php
try {$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql;dbname=menu;charset=utf8mb4", "user", 
"pass", array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
} catch (\PDOException $e) {throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());};

$org = "1";

try {
$sql = "DELETE FROM menu where org=?";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$org]);
echo "Record deleted successfully";
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `org="1"` in the table?

Comment: BTW, you need to use `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` in the options array. Otherwise you won't get exceptions for errors.

Comment: Thanks, got it - was a stupid mistake... User account didn't have DELETE privileges

Comment: That'll do it. And since you didn't enable exceptions, you didn't see the error message.